# Trying to combine a class file into one single java file

Tags: java

I'm trying to avoid using two files and instead, just make it into one file all together.

So i made a single class in a .java file, this is how it looks:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Raindrop {

    double [] rainfallStats;

    public double getTotalRainfall() {
        double totalRainfall;

        for ( int index = 0; index < rainfallStats.length; index++) {
            totalRainfall = totalRainfall + rainfallStats[ index ];
        }
        return totalRainfall;
    }

    public double getAverageRainfall() {
        return getTotalRainfall() / rainfallStats.length;
    }

    public double getMostRainMonth () {
        double mostRain = rainfallStats [ 0 ];
        int mostRainMonth;

        for( int index = 0; index < rainfallStats.length; index++ ) {
            if ( rainfallStats[ index ] > mostRain ) {
                mostRain = rainfallStats [ index ];
                mostRainMonth = index + 1;
            }
        }
        return mostRainMonth;
    }

    public double getLeastRainMonth () {
       double leastRain = rainfallStats [ 0 ];
       int leastRainMonth;

       for( int index = 0; index < rainfallStats.length; index++ ) {
           if ( rainfallStats[ index ] > leastRain ) {
               leastRain = rainfallStats [ index ];
               leastRainMonth = index + 1;
           }
       }
       return leastRainMonth;
    }

    public Rainfall ( double [] rainfallStatsGiven) {
        rainfallStats = new double [ rainfallStatsGiven.length ];
        for (int index = 0; index < rainfallStatsGiven; index++) {
            rainfallStats[ index ] = rainfallStatsGiven [ index ];
        }
    }


    public static void fillArrayWithUserInput ( double [] arrayGiven ) {
        String userInputString;
        double userMonthlyRainfallFigure;

        for ( int index = 0; index < arrayGiven.length; index++ ){
            userInputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "Please enter rainfall figures for month " + (index + 1) );
            userMonthlyRainfallFigure = Double.parseDouble( userInputString );
            arrayGiven [ index ] = userMonthlyRainfallFigure;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int MONTH_IN_A_YEAR = 12;
        double [] rainfallStats = new double [12];
        String userOutputString;

        fillArrayWithUserInput( rainfallStats );

        Rainfall rainfallData = new Rainfall( rainfallStats );

        userOutputString = String.format ( 
                "Total rainfall: %f\nAverage monthly rainfall" + ":" 
                        + "%f\nMonth with most rain: %f\nMonth with least rain: %f", 
                                rainfallData.getTotalRainfall(),
                                rainfallData.getAverageRainfall(),
                                rainfallData.getMostRainMonth(),
                                rainfallData.getLeastRainMonth() );

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, userOutputString );

        System.exit( 0 );
    }

}
```

I get the error:

```
Raindrop.java:45: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
public Rainfall ( double [] rainfallStatsGiven) {
       ^
1 error
```

I try changing `public Rainfall` into a methoed but it couldnt figure out how to do it, would like any suggestion on how to make this work. I couldnt figure out how to nest the class ethier , and i couldnt figure out how to make the public class into anything else that would work.

Comment: "*Im trying to avoid using two files and instead just make it into one file all together.*" - One question: why? Following the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), splitting up the responsibility in separate classes is actually good style.

Comment: To the actual error: The second class was called `Rainfall`, right? The method in line 45 is a constructor. This is why the method has a special syntax (missing return type, same name as class). Without knowing more details, we cannot really help you further.

Comment: yea, but basicly what im trying to accomplish is merging a class file to a .java file so instead of having to find the class file, it already in the java file just dont know how to do it.

Comment: Uhm... what? You cannot merge a .class-file (i.e. bytecode) into a .java-file.

Comment: my professor doest want class files, he only want the .java file

Comment: java compiler (javac) compiles java source code (.java) into bytecode (.class) which is a binary file. The latter is interpreted by java virtual machine (jvm) and gets executed.

Comment: Better ask you profressor for assistance. As-is, your question is unclear. Even if it were clear, your professors/supervisors should the first you should ask. For one, they get payed to educate you. Furthermore, they know what and how they want to teach, so it is more likely they give you a more accurate answer than we can.

Comment: well im trying to say is instead of having a seprate file that has all the methodes, i have it in one file so i made a seprate file with the methoed and another file that excute the file, but instead have copied and pasted into one file.

Comment: hence why thiers a public Rainfall and public Raindrop, basicly im trying so combine the file but i dont know how to.

Comment: This is not the question you initially asked. You asked about a specific syntax error. To answer the question you just aked, we need more information (i.e. both `Rainfall` and `Raindrop). You should ask this as a separate (new) question. But the question still is: why would you want to merge two separate concerns into one Java-class?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to look through my code again and found many errors and fixed them which,in the process, fixed my problem because there were many more problem, so i was able to get what I wanted.
Heres the revised one if anyone also want to look at:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 public class Rainfall {

   double [] rainfallStats;

   public double getTotalRainfall() {
       double totalRainfall =0;

       for ( int index = 0; index < rainfallStats.length; index++) {
       totalRainfall = totalRainfall + rainfallStats[ index ];
       }
       return totalRainfall;
   }

    public double getAverageRainfall() {
      return getTotalRainfall() / rainfallStats.length;
   }

   public double getMostRainMonth () {
       double mostRain = rainfallStats [ 0 ];
       int mostRainMonth = 1;

       for( int index = 0; index < rainfallStats.length; index++ ) {
           if ( rainfallStats[ index ] > mostRain ) {
               mostRain = rainfallStats [ index ];
               mostRainMonth = index + 1;
           }
       }
       return mostRainMonth;
  }

  public double getLeastRainMonth () {
       double leastRain = rainfallStats [ 0 ];
       int leastRainMonth =1;

       for( int index = 0; index < rainfallStats.length; index++ ) {
           if ( rainfallStats[ index ] < leastRain ) {
               leastRain = rainfallStats [ index ];
               leastRainMonth = index + 1;
           }
       }
       return leastRainMonth;
  }

    public Rainfall ( double [] rainfallStatsGiven) {
       rainfallStats = new double [ rainfallStatsGiven.length ];
    for (int index = 0; index < rainfallStatsGiven.length; index++) {
       rainfallStats[ index ] = rainfallStatsGiven [ index ];
       }
}


public static void fillArrayWithUserInput ( double [] arrayGiven ) {
    String userInputString;
    double userMonthlyRainfallFigure;

    for ( int index = 0; index < arrayGiven.length; index++ ){
    userInputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter rainfall figures for month " + (index + 1) );
    userMonthlyRainfallFigure = Double.parseDouble( userInputString );
    arrayGiven [ index ] = userMonthlyRainfallFigure;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int MONTH_IN_A_YEAR = 12;
    double [] rainfallStats = new double [12];
    String userOutputString;

    fillArrayWithUserInput( rainfallStats );

    Rainfall rainfallData = new Rainfall( rainfallStats );

    userOutputString = String.format ( "Total rainfall: %f\nAverage monthly rainfall"+
                                        ":+ %f\nMonth with most rain: %f\nMonth with least rain: %f",
                                    rainfallData.getTotalRainfall(),
                                    rainfallData.getAverageRainfall(),
                                    rainfallData.getMostRainMonth(),
                                    rainfallData.getLeastRainMonth() );

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, userOutputString );

    System.exit( 0 );
        }

}
```